# IMPORTXML table with alternating rows

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I would like to use the Google Sheet IMPORTXML function to import only the '1B' column from [this](http://www.fangraphs.com/statsd.aspx?playerid=9166&position=C&type=1&gds=&gde=&season=2015) Fangraphs page.

I am able to use this function:

```
=importxml("http://www.fangraphs.com/statsd.aspx?playerid=9166&position=C&type=1&gds=&gde=&season=2015", "//tr[@class='rgRow']/td[10]")
```

to import *EVERY OTHER* row in the table, because the table is split into two classes of 'rgRow' and 'rgAltRow.' However, I need to import *every* row.

I would also like to import all the way down the list, not stopping at each new  header.

How could this be done? I would rather **not** use multiple IMPORTXML functions in order to keep the page running quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is an xpath query, try this:

```
=importxml("http://www.fangraphs.com/statsd.aspx?playerid=9166&position=C&type=1&gds=&gde=&season=2015", "//tr[@class='rgRow']/td[10] | //tr[@class='rgAltRow']/td[10]")
```

Note the addition of the `|` character (for 'or') and the second expression of `//tr[@class='rgAltRow']/td[10]`